# How to add one day in date in datastage server

Tags: datastage

How to add one day in VDate column where column VDate value is not fixed.

Example:

**input** *VDate = "2013-02-07"*

**output** *VDate = "2013-02-08"*

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the date into a date type, then you can add or subtract days.

IConv converts a string into a datastage internal date format.  Then you can perform addition/subtraction on the date.  Then use OConv to convert the variable back to string format.

If this is done in a transformer stage, you need to do this all in one statement:

OConv(Iconv(VDate ,"D/YMD[4,2,2]") + 1), "D/YMD[4,2,2]")

http://www.dsxchange.com/viewtopic.php?p=330354&sid=bf68da51aa1b8e81c41a68a9233b7634